# Full-trust SharePoint hosted app licensing

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-hosted-app, licensing

As we know, [Apps for SharePoint that request full-control permissions are not accepted in the Office Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220035.aspx).

So, how to implement licensing management and validation then? 
Especially for **SharePoint hosted** App.

Answer (score 0):

check these MSDN articles may help you.

- [Licensing your apps for SharePoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/11/09/licensing-your-apps-for-sharepoint.aspx)
- [SharePoint 2013 hosted App License check](http://keutmann.blogspot.dk/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-hosted-app-license-check.html)
- [Creating and verifying licensing in a paid app for Office](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/11/01/creating-and-verifying-licensing-in-a-paid-app-for-office.aspx)

Comment: These articles explain licensing management for apps in Store, but Apps that request full-control permissions are not accepted in the Office Store.

Answer (score 0):

By the moment we haven't found any other way then using general JS protecting/licensing library(like JScrambler).